# How to read a large amount of images (more than a million) and process them efficiently

Tags: c++, image, opencv, boost, large-data

I have a program which performs some computations on images to produce other images. The system works with small amount of images used as an input and I would like to know how to make it work for large amounts of input data; like a million or more images. My main concern is how to store the input images and how to store the output (produced) images.

I have a function `compute(const std:vector<cv::Mat>&)` which makes computations on 124 images (due to GPU memory limitations). Because the algorithm is iterative it takes different amount of iterations for each image to produce the output image.

Right now, if I provide more than 124 images then the function computes for the first 124 images and when an image finishes its computation, then it is swapped with another one. I would like the algorithm to be used with larger inputs, like a million, or more, images. The computation function returns one output image for each input image and it is implemented like:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> compute(std::vector<cv::Mat>& image_vec) {

  std::vector<cv::Mat> output_images(image_vec.size());

  std::vector<cv::Mat> tmp_images(124);

  processed_images = 0;
  while (processed_images < image_vec.size()) {

    // make computations and update the output_images 
    // for the images that are currently in processed

    // remove the images that finished from the tmp_images
    // and update the processed_images variable

    // import new images to tmp_images unless there 
    // are no more in the input vector
  }

  return output_images;
}
```

I am using the `boost::filesystem` to read images from a folder (also I use `OpenCV` to read and store each image) at the beginning of the program:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> read_images_from_dir(std::string dir_name) {

  std::vector<cv::Mat> image_vec;

  boost::filesystem::path p(dir_name);

  std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> tmp_vec;

  std::copy(boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(p),
            boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(),
            back_inserter(tmp_vec));

  std::vector<boost::filesystem::path>::const_iterator it = tmp_vec.begin();

  for (; it != tmp_vec.end(); ++it) {

    if (is_regular_file(*it)) {
      //std::cout << it->string() << std::endl;
      image_vec.push_back(read_image(it->string()));
    }
  }

  return image_vec;
}
```

And then the main program looks like this:

```
void main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  // suppose for this example that argv[1] contains a correct 
  // path to a folder which contains images
  std::vector<cv::Mat> input_images = read_images_from_dir(argv[1]);

  std::vector<cv::Mat> output_images = compute(input_images);

  // save the output_images
}
```

[Here](https://ideone.com/OB2Zcv) you can find the program in an online editor, if you wish.
Any sugestion that clarifies the question is welcomed.

Edit: Some of the answers and comments pointed out useful design decisions that I have to make, so that you will be able to answer the question. I would like to mention that:

- The images are/will be already stored in the disk before the program starts.
- The process will be done "offline" without new data comming and will be done once every few hours (or days). This is because the parameters of the program will change after it finishes.
- I can tolerate not having the fastest possible implementation at first because I want to make things work and then consider for optimizations.
- The code has many computations so the I/O so far does not take that much time.
- I expect this code to run on a single machine, but I think it will be better to NOT have multithreading, as a first version, so that the code will be more portable and so that I can integrate it in another program that does not use mutlithreading and I do not want to have more dependencies.

One implementations that I thought about, is reading batches of data (say 5K images) and after computing their output load new data. But I do not know if there is something far better without too much additional complexity. Of course, any answer is welcomed.

Comment: 1. Why are you storing these images? You said it yourself, you only want to “read” the images and produce new images from those. You only need to read the data from the original images and handle the creation of the new ones systematically. Don’t use a vector, too much copying, stream those files as you iterator over that path, creating a new file as you walk over a new image.
2. Depending on your actual process there could be room for improvement, but we don’t know because the ops have yet to be written. Scaling questions are natural to the problem there are addressing.

Comment: I think it can help if you uses two threads, one for reading and writing and the other for computing; then, while computing, you can read input_images and write output_images, always having input_images waiting in queue. And try to optimize everything with every trick available... http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_cpp.pdf

Comment: Without digging into too much, the scalability will be limited but the CPU/GPU availability.  A threaded architecture that keeps each of CPU/GPU near 100% will likely result and best throughput. Many graphics routines are CPU bound so starting more threads that number of cores isn't likely to help.  On the I/O side, the scalability limit will be the bound by the I/O limit of the disk array or controller card.  If possible, distribute your images across multiple physical disk array. Doing large read/writes is usually best. Likely one read and one write thread will be enough.

Comment: One easy way to improve performance is to run multiple copies of your program at a time with **GNU Parallel**. Loading and holding thousands of pictures at a time does not seem a very good use of RAM either.